# View pager containing a sliding drawer with a view pager inside

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slidingdrawer

I have a view pager that loads different fragment as you swipe through and the last fragment is a view pager itself. In the field trip app, they do something similar where you swipe through the views and the last view is a google map. Once you get to the map you can move the map around without swiping back to the previous view but there is a sliding drawer handle on the side for when you do want to leave the map. That's the functionality I'm going for but am having trouble figuring out how it all works. Has anyone done anything similar to this or have any ideas. I've been able to disable the top level view pager but can't get the view pager inside of the sliding drawer to swipe the views afterwards.